# how to change custom authorizer from type token to type request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a custom authorizer function which only receives the authorization token from client side but I want to send more information in the headers to the custom authorizer.
Now, from what I have read my understanding is that this can happen only if I change the type to request and then I'll be able to access other parameters and headers too instead of just authorization.
so, how do I convert my custom authorizer type to 'request'??

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS CLI [update-authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-authorizer.html):

```
aws apigateway update-authorizer\
  --rest-api-id 1234123412\
  --authorizer-id gfi4n3 
  --patch-operations op='replace',path='/type',value='REQUEST'
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more?
where do I put this code?

Comment: Install AWS CLI on your machine, configure it and run the command. See here for more about it: https://aws.amazon.com/cli/